# Avg. CPU usage on NewRelic

Tags: ios, cpu-usage, newrelic

NewRelic is showing Avg. CPU usage as 11200% for my app. What could be the issue. My app seems to work fine on my iPhone and no user ever reported any battery degradation because of my app. Is there anyone else facing the same issue? How to debug?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Infrastructure Hosts page](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/infrastructure/new-relic-infrastructure/infrastructure-ui-pages/infrastructure-hosts-page-measure-resource-usage) calculate [CPU average](https://docs.newrelic.com/attribute-dictionary/systemsample/cpupercent) using several attributes

> CPU percentage is not collected by New Relic, but derived from several other metrics. Specifically, the cpuPercent attribute is **an aggregation** of `cpuUserPercent`, `cpuSystemPercent`, `cpuIoWaitPercent` and `cpuStealPercent`

Probably at least one of them is wrong

You can ask this question (or report a bug) in [discuss newrelic infrastructure](https://discuss.newrelic.com/c/support-products-agents/new-relic-infrastructure)

Or write [NRQL query in Insights](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/infrastructure/manage-your-data/data-instrumentation/default-infrastructure-events) to check these attributes using [SystemSample](https://docs.newrelic.com/attribute-dictionary?attribute_name=&events_tids%5B%5D=8407)

> To query Infrastructure event data, use the NRQL syntax with the Insights Data Explorer:
>
> Go to insights.newrelic.com  > Data Explorer.
>   From the query command line, use FROM before the event type.

```
select cpuUserPercent , cpuSystemPercent , cpuIOWaitPercent , cpuStealPercent from SystemSample
```

Comment: But is it possible that any app could achieve such high cpu rate?

Comment: It's been a couple years since I've used the New Relic mobile SDKs, but I remember seeing that issue come and go, usually after a major iOS release.

Comment: @Swati it seems as a bug, but you can ask it in discuss newrelic site

Answer (score 0):

It means there is more than one CPU or core.

[Newrelic-Docs](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/apm/new-relic-apm/troubleshooting/cpu-usage-mismatch-or-usage-over-100)

Thanks.